# Angular error [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to code for the first time ever in Angular, and I can't load an expression on my page because I get the error [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module. I know there are a lot of similar issues on stackoverflow but none of them have solved my issue. The link to app.js is not broken.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type"text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javscript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    <p>{{ "hello" + "there"}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);
})();
```

I am just trying this locally on my computer. Thanks!

Comment: Why is it looking for myApp when your app is called store?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I hadn't updated my copy of the error.. that was me trying to get it to work earlier. I'll update the issue

Comment: can be caused by a simple syntax error .... or possibly your path to js file isn't correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only problem are the typos in the code.

There's an `=` missing in the first script (**line 5**) and it's written `javscript` instead of `javascript` in the second script (**line 6**)

Try the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module('store', []);
    })();
  </script>

  <p>{{ "hello" + "there"}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I just copied what you wrote and it didn't fix it. What specifically is the typo?

Comment: Always check to see all javascript files have been loaded in your browser.